# Python fails to open 11gb csv in r+ mode but opens in r mode

Tags: python, windows, file-io

I'm having problems with some code that loops through a bunch of .csvs and deletes the final line if there's nothing in it (i.e. files that end with the `\n` newline character)

My code works successfully on all files except one, which is the largest file in the directory at 11gb.  The second largest file is 4.5gb.

The line it fails on is simply:

```
with open(path_str,"r+") as my_file:
```

and I get the following message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r+') or filename: 'F:\\Shapefiles\\ab_premium\\processed_csvs\\a.csv'
```

The `path_str` I create using `os.file.join` to avoid errors, and I tried renaming the file to `a.csv` just to make sure there wasn't anything odd going on with the filename.  This made no difference.

Even more strangely, the file is happy to open in r mode.  I.e. the following code works fine:

```
with open(path_str,"r") as my_file:
```

I have tried navigating around the file in read mode, and it's happy to read characters at the start, end, and in the middle of the file.

Does anyone know of any limits on the size of file that Python can deal with or why I might be getting this error?  I'm on Windows 7 64bit and have 16gb of RAM.

Comment: It must be due to text mode. Does `r+b` work?

Comment: Is your program doing anything else with these csv files, or is it simply removing the excess trailing newline(s)?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. Yes - it's just removing the trailing newlines.  If you have an easier solution to this problem I'm all ears :-)  Here is the code:   https://gist.github.com/RobinL/9895b764ca3ce61c8e37.  I didn't ask for an alternative solution in the question because I'm curious to find out the source of this problem.

Comment: @DanD. - yes r+b works.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Window, but I _suspect_ that the failure to open _might_ be due to lack of memory for buffering a text file you want to modify. So it would be great if you can test if `'r+b'` mode works, as Dan D. suggested.

Comment: Ok! The simple solution is to modify your code to work with a binary file, which on Windows means you'll need to look for `\r\n` sequences instead of plain `\n`. You may also be interested in using the [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) module.

Comment: @PM2Ring I deliberately wrote the code so it wouldn't have to read the whole file (see the gist).  e.g. reading the ~4gb files uses almost no memory.  That doesn't mean your explanation is wrong - it just means I still don't really understand the source of the problem!  I've just been experimenting following the suggestion of `r+b` and yes - I'm able to make the code working using the `\r\b` solution as you suggest -thanks very much

Comment: Even though your script isn't reading the entire file contents into RAM, the fact that `'r+b'` mode works tends to support the theory that some buffering is being done by Python or Windows to enable the automatic line-ending conversions done for text mode files. But hopefully a Windows expert will shed more light on this matter.

Comment: @PM It's not done by Windows - the conversion happens on Linux too.

Comment: @Veedrac: Ok. I'm still using Python 2 (2.6.6), where [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) doesn't take a `newlines` parameter, but newline conversion can be controlled by a `'U'` in the mode parameter, assuming that Python was built with universal newlines support. According to my tests, no conversion happens in Linux for files opened with `'rt'` or `'r+t'`. However, (as I've just learned), the situation is different for the Python 3 [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#open), where newline conversion is performed if `newlines` is `None`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default I/O stack in Python 2 is layered over CRT `FILE` streams. On Windows these are built on top of a POSIX emulation API that uses file descriptors (which in turn is layered over the user-mode Windows API, which is layered over the kernel-mode I/O system, which itself is a deeply layered system based on I/O request packets; the hardware is down there somewhere...). In the POSIX layer, opening a file with `_O_RDWR | _O_TEXT` mode (as in "r+"), requires seeking to the end of the file to remove CTRL+Z, if it's present. Here's a quote from the CRT's [`fopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation:

> Open in text (translated) mode. In this mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted as
>   an end-of-file character on input. In files opened for reading/writing
>   with "a+", fopen checks for a CTRL+Z at the end of the file and
>   removes it, if possible. This is done because using fseek and ftell to
>   move within a file that ends with a CTRL+Z, may cause fseek to behave
>   improperly near the end of the file.

The problem here is that the above check calls the 32-bit [`_lseek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yee101t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (bear in mind that `sizeof long` is 4 bytes on 64-bit Windows, unlike most other 64-bit platforms), instead of `_lseeki64`. Obviously this fails for an 11 GB file. Specifically, [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541) fails because it gets called with a `NULL` value for `lpDistanceToMoveHigh`. Here's the return value and `LastErrorValue` for the latter call:

```
0:000> kc 2
Call Site
KERNELBASE!SetFilePointer
MSVCR90!lseek_nolock

0:000> r rax                       
rax=00000000ffffffff

0:000> dt _TEB @$teb LastErrorValue
ntdll!_TEB
   +0x068 LastErrorValue : 0x57
```

The error code 0x57 is [`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382#ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). This is referring to `lpDistanceToMoveHigh` being `NULL` when trying to seek from the end of a large file.

To work around this problem with CRT `FILE` streams, I recommend opening the file using [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#module-interface) instead. This is  a backported implementation of Python 3's I/O stack. It always opens files in raw binary mode (`_O_BINARY`), and it implements its own buffering and text-mode layers on top of the raw layer.

```
>>> import io                    
>>> f = io.open('a.csv', 'r+')
>>> f     
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='a.csv' encoding='cp1252'>
>>> f.buffer   
<_io.BufferedRandom name='a.csv'>
>>> f.buffer.raw
<_io.FileIO name='a.csv' mode='rb+'>
>>> f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
11811160064L
```

Comment: At last, someone who knows what's _really_ going on. :) I didn't even _think_ about that pesky Ctrl-Z...

Comment: This is a brilliant answer - exactly the information I was trying to search google for with no success. Thanks.